# Knockout with repeat binding: Initially selected value being overwritten

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have a preset value for a select `selectedValue` which has a value of "ham".
I have 3 options "spam", "ham", "cheese".

When the viewmodel is applied, the "ham" value is *selected*, but the `selectedValue` looses it's value, so "ham" isn't actually selected although it appears to be.

What do I need to change to allow for `selectValue` to retain it's initial value?
Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X4NNk/5/)

**Html**

```
<select data-bind="value:selectedValue">
   <option data-bind="repeat: values" 
        data-repeat-bind="value: $item(), text: $item()">
   </option>
</select>
<br>selectedValue: <span data-bind="text:selectedValue"></span>
```

**ViewModel**

```
var viewModel = function () {
    this.selectedValue = ko.observable("ham"); //initial value has been chosen.
    this.values = ko.observableArray(["spam", 'ham', 'cheese']);
    this.showMeSelectedValue = function(){alert(this.selectedValue())};
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

**Note:** 
I am using the repeat binding from https://github.com/mbest/knockout-repeat. I would usually use the regular options binding, but I need to repeat binding for select labels to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few different ways that you could handle this one.  I think that an easy way would be to use a custom binding that applies binding to its children first.

Here is an example:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.bindChildren = {
    init: function(element, valueAcessor, allBindings, vm, bindingContext) {
        //bind children first
        ko.applyBindingsToDescendants(bindingContext, element);

        //tell KO not to bind the children itself
        return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
    }
};
```

Now, you would specify:

```
<select data-bind="bindChildren: true, value: selectedValue">
    <option data-bind="repeat: values" data-repeat-bind="value: $item(), text: $item()"></option>
</select>
```

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/r9kPm/

Comment: I edited this to use the binding context instead of the view model when binding descendants. That way they have access to `$root`, `$parent`, etc.