# How do I reuse a select list in Knockout.js for better performance?

Tags: performance, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have a view that shows small edit forms for all employees at a given location, one below the other. One of the controls shown for each employee is a select list of 150 cities. A change event on that select list transfers the employee to another location.

```
<select data-bind="options: $root.locations(),
    optionsCaption: 'Please choose...',
    optionsText: function(item) { return item.locationname(); },
    optionsValue: 'uuid',
    value: reassign_to_locationuuid,
    event: {change: $root.reassignLocation}">
</select>
```

This works fine, but the largest location has 79 people, and when that page loads, it takes a while -- nothing crazy, only about 10 seconds, and I have a nice hypnotic loading animation in place while the user waits. But I wonder how to improve load speed and my Knockout-fu, before this becomes a bigger problem.

When I load the page with these select lists commented out, it renders in <2s. The slowdown is from [my bad design of] having KO repeat the work of building a select list of 150 items 79 times. Since they are the *exact same lists*, with each just bound to a different employee's reassign_to_locationuuid property, I wonder if it can be made to run faster.

This has been a tough one to Google because:

- searching with *multiple select lists in knockout.js* brings up a ton of info on select lists that allow multiple selections
- searching with *reuse template in knockout.js* brings up a lot of helpful info on named templates

I tried to go with a named template, but learned that those seem to be for situations where you want to pass different data into the same layout -- I'm passing the same data each time.

When I searched for *knockout.js performance* I found Ryan Niemeyer's  http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/06/knockoutjs-performance-gotcha-3-all-bindings.html

To try to determine whether the problem described there (all bindings firing at once) was my issue too, I downloaded Michael Best's knockout-repeat from https://github.com/mbest/knockout-repeat and changed my select lists to use that approach:

```
<select data-bind="value: reassign_to_locationuuid, 
                   event: {change: $root.reassignLocation}">
    <option value="">Please choose...</option>
    <option data-bind="repeat: $root.locations()" 
            data-repeat-bind="attr: { value: $item().uuid() }, 
                              text: $item().locationname()">
    </option>
</select>
```

...but the timings were near-identical, so that doesn't seem to be it.

Thank you Michael & Ryan for answering [Knockout with repeat binding: Initially selected value being overwritten](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18256618/knockout-with-repeat-binding-initially-selected-value-being-overwritten) -- as I found that solution yesterday and it helped me get the knockout-repeat test above to work (it's just not any faster).

Given that the reassign_to_locationuuid property starts out as null for every employee when the page loads, and that the first change to any one of these lists will navigate away from this page when the *reassignLocation* event fires, I feel like I'm doing something wrong.

1. In this situation, can I get KO to do most of its work only once instead of 79 times?
2. Am I using KO for this part when I shouldn't be? Maybe I don't need all the rich KO binding goodness here in these lists?
3. Could some of this list-building happen asynchronously somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to reuse the same location list for every person. I've simplified your task by stripping some properties off and written the example implementation of your problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/PqqHK/

300 locations and 100 persons are being loaded only once (onload). Location list for every person does not need to be rendered for every person separately, since person data keeps and tracks location id and proper location item in `select` is selected on person change.

```
<div data-bind="with: selectedPerson">
    <p>
        <b>Id:</b>
        <span data-bind="text: id"></span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <b>Name:</b>
        <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <b>Location:</b>
        <select data-bind="options: $root.locations,
            optionsValue: 'id',
            optionsText: 'name',
            value: location"></select>
        <i>Select another value to relocate!</i>
    </p>
</div>
```

Person constructor:

```
function Person(id, name, locId) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.location = ko.observable(locId);
}
```

Model:

```
ko.applyBindings(vm = {
    persons: persons,
    locations: locations,
    selectedPerson: ko.observable()
});
```

Comment: Thank you! In my case, everyone has to show up with their own location select list showing. I'd really like to learn how to make that heavier type of view go as quickly as possible, so I forked http://jsfiddle.net/8NkqC/2/ to use foreach to show one form per person. I also doubled the # of list items vs. my largest real case... and this fiddle still runs 3x faster than my code!

I think the reason is that I use ko.mapping() on my incoming JSON, so every property of every item is an observable. I'll refactor it so that I'm observing only what I **need** to, like your example.

Comment: Good try. I didn't know you want to display persons as separate sections on page. There is one more option in your case that could help to increase performance for long lists - pagination. Rendering 20 or 30 persons per page will greatly increase loading speed rather than rendering of hundreds at once.